# Difference entre « prison ferme » et « prison ouverte » ?

Tags: vocabulaire

Récemment à un match de foot entre Croatie et la République tchèque, quelques-uns des supporteurs ont jeté des fumigènes au terrain. Je regardais les nouvelles en français et la présentatrice a décrit leurs peines:

> ... trois autres avaient déjà été jugés condamnés à douze, dix-huit, et vingt-quatre mois de prison ferme.

Qu'elle est la différence entre « prison ferme », « prison ouverte », et « prison » en général ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Ferme** n'a pas de lien direct avec **fermé**, mais avec **fermeté** ( rigoureux, dur ).

**Prison ferme** s'oppose à **prison avec sursis**. Dans le premier cas, il y a (normalement) incarcération immédiate, dans le deuxième cas, la condamnation ne pourra être appliquée qu'en cas de récidive.

Il existe bien une **prison ouverte** en France, celle de [Casabianda](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centre_de_d%C3%A9tention_de_Casabianda) située à Aléria en Corse, dénuée de barreaux, murs d'enceinte et miradors mais les détenus y font quand même de la prison ferme.